# How can I nest each item in an array within each other in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

If I have the following array:

```php
[
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'baz' 
]
```

How can I get this output with PHP dynamically:

```php
[
  'foo' => [
    'bar' => [
      'baz' => []
    ]
  ]
]
```

**EDIT**

I ended up achieving it by building the array backward and keeping track of the last key, but I would be interested in a cleaner recursive approach:

```
$arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
$new_arr = [];
$last_key = null;

foreach ( array_reverse( $arr ) as $item ) {
    if ( $last_key ) {
        $new_arr[ $item ] = $new_arr;
        unset( $new_arr[ $last_key ] );
        $last_key = $item;
    } else {
        $new_arr[ $item ] = [];
        $last_key = $item; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Using recursion is one of the ways to achieve that. Is there anything you've done to achieve your result? Such question without any attempts shown tend to have very negative reactions from the community

Comment: might as well join your array and use json_decode https://3v4l.org/u3WS0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `foreach` you don't have to unset or use an if/else.

You could reverse the `$arr`, and wrap the `$new_arr` (the result) inside a new array for each iteration using the value of `$arr` as the key.

```
$arr = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz'
];

$new_arr = [];

foreach(array_reverse($arr) as $v) {
    $new_arr = [$v => $new_arr];
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/9pfam).

Output

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [baz] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hah, I think this is what I was trying to do but I made it way more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ];

$new_arr = array_reduce(array_reverse($arr), static fn($carry, $item) => [ $item => $carry ], []);
```

Steps:

1. Reverse the array.
2. Reduce the reversed array. On each iteration return *[ $item => $carry ]*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function buildNestedArray($arr) {
  if (!$arr) {
    return [];
  }
  return [ $arr[0] => buildNestedArray(array_slice($arr, 1))];
}
```